How do I configure Microsoft Copilot for a multitenant app with PKCE?
I am configuring Microsoft Copilot for a multitenant application that uses PKCE in its OAuth 2.0 flow. What steps and configurations are required to enable secure cross-origin authorization code redemption in this environment?
The main goal is to:
Have a CoPilot in the one Tenant and then it should work with data source of the different tenant as well.
